# $f$ continuous on $(a,b)$ and $|f| \leq M$ results in $f$ integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

> $f$ continuous on $(a,b)$ and $|f| \leq M$ results in $f$ integrable on $[a,b]$

I used the above statement in my test. As I know for sure that if $f$ is continuous at almost every point in an interval $[a,b]$ and bounded so $f$ is integrable in this interval $[a,b]$.

So if I know $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ it means it's continuous in $[a,b]$ for every $x \neq a,b$. And there is real number $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for every x in the interval $(a,b)$. Therefore, integrable in $[a,b]$.

It can be undefined at $x=a,b$ or any other form of discontinuity.
Please let me know if I am wrong using the Riemann theory.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Telling us which theory of integration to consider might be useful...

Comment: @zwim the theory is Riemann. I will edit it .

Comment: That’s right, but do you know how to prove it?

Comment: Continuous on (a,b) does not imply that $f$ is bounded. You need it to be continuous on all of [a,b]

Comment: @monoidaltransform
Okay so I wrote it’s blocked meaning bounded(now edited), sorry for the English . if it's bounded at $(a,b)$ so of course bounded for $[a,b]$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo
 During the exam there is no need to directly prove it as we have like book which we can use to prove . In the book there is this “if f is continuous for almost every point at [a,b] and bounded in this interval so f is integrable in [a,b]. “ theory so I wrote according to this page …. I wasn’t just sure if it’s every kind of discontinuity.

Comment: it doesn’t matter what kind of discontinuity (that’s why the theorem doesn’t mention it).

Comment: @You should specify as "Riemann integrable," otherwise it is trivial.

Comment: @AliMezher OP already specified they’re talking about Riemann integrals (in the comment above, and the post as well). Besides, this theorem takes the same amount of effort for both Riemann and Lebesgue integrals (proving an a.e continuous function is Lebesgue-measurable is so standard a fact we think of it as trivial, but really, it still takes a few lines to prove from scratch).

Comment: @AliMezher
yeah the only thing I didn't explain is why f is bounded in $[a,b]$ which unfortunate because it's really easy to prove.